# How can you access files after being compiled to a single python executable?

Tags: python

I have a python script that reads a local file (let's call it `file.foo`). When I compile the script, I need that local file inside the executable so i use *pyinstaller* like this:

```
> pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "file.foo"  "script.py"
```

The thing is, when I run the executable, my script cannot find `file.foo` which is embedded with it.

Is there a way to read files compiled within the executable?

PS: I would prefer using `--onefile` to keep it closed source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyinstaller will unpack your file into a temporary folder at runtime inside the operating system TEMP folder, so in order to get the path of the file after it is unpacked using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/15649230)

```py
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

then to get the path of the data, just use

```py
data_path = resource_path("file.foo")
with open(data_path,'r') as f:
    pass # read it as you normally would
```

just a note, `--onefile` can cause some libraries not to work, so make sure you test your dependences first.