# correct path for files with PIL after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pystray

I'm using auto-py-to-exe which is based on pyinstaller, trying to make an executable with --onefile, using pystray to make a tray app, but after compiling I get an error that the icon file cannot be found.
See that in the code I tried to use os.path to get the most specific path possible, even so it is not possible to find.

The question is, how to make this path correct using --onfile?

```py
import pystray
from PIL import Image
# ==============================
from os.path import join
from os import getcwd


TilleTables = SetInterval(1, TileTables)
# print(join(getcwd(), 'icon.png'))
menuImg = Image.open(join(getcwd(), 'icon.png'))

MenuIcon = pystray.Icon('Neural', menuImg, menu=pystray.Menu(
    pystray.MenuItem('Exit', HandleTrayClick),

))

MenuIcon.run()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "PIL\Image.py", line 3092, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icon.png'
```

[Auto-py-to-exe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioFUq.png)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZba7.png)

Comment: uploaded code @RahulKP

Comment: yes that was my first try, the error is the same @RahulKP

Comment: How did you tell pyinstaller it needs that file?  pyinstaller has no idea what files you need unless you tell it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Now I've added to a adicional files field, but same error
https://i.imgur.com/F7uuqit.png

Comment: possibly a duplicate of this question [Pyinstaller executable saves files to temp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405069/pyinstaller-executable-saves-files-to-temp-folder/70405825#70405825) and this question [How can you access files after being compiled to a single python executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73433075/how-can-you-access-files-after-being-compiled-to-a-single-python-executable/73433308#73433308)

Comment: OK, but you need to know (a) where does pyinstaller put the file, and (b) what directory is the current directory when you run.

Comment: @TimRoberts
ye, pyinstaller seem's me to placing on '.'
https://i.imgur.com/ZA74eJH.png
And now I'm trying to use this one example from auto-py-to-exe helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741

But even if I use 'resource_path' function and set img `menuImg = Image.open(resource_path('icon.png'))`  don't work

Comment: you can just open your temp folder and find the image location, it's usually in your `AppData\Local\Temp`, make sure you open it while your application is running ... like before you close the error message, or show us what your "current command" looks like

Comment: @AhmedAEK solved, I added a temp and resources path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the path of pyinstaller must be relative after the build, so it is necessary to add the function that creates a temporary file for the icon...
[Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741)

the solution found was to add the patch to this function and within the auto-py-to-exe set the icon file to the additional files

```py
menuImg = Image.open(resource_path('icon.png'))

MenuIcon = pystray.Icon('Neural', menuImg, menu=pystray.Menu(
    pystray.MenuItem('Exit', HandleTrayClick),

))

MenuIcon.run()
```

So the icon appears in the temp folder and can be found by the program.

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way of doing it...